# Way to determine if files on Windows 10 PC have been copied or accessed

Tags: windows-10, security

Is there a way to find out if a PC has been accessed by a USB-based operating system? For example, if files have been copied off it? The PC in question has no boot drive at the time but the data drives are installed. The boot drive is running Win 10 x64 and using the system is using the usual NTFS file system. Would timestamps on files change? Or is there a way to determine if the drives have been powered on before the the boot drive was reinstalled?

Answer (score 2):

The file access timestamps *may* have been modified, but don't count on it. Not every operation modifies the access timestamp (for example, querying the timestamps themselves, and related metadata, usually doesn't). Additionally, somebody who was trying to cover their tracks would reset the timestamps to their original value (this is easy). Alternatively and more easily, they could have used a file system driver that doesn't update the access time stamp (this is sometimes done legitimately, for performance reasons), or mounted the entire partition(s) as read-only, or cloned the disk at the block device level (never mounting any file systems from it at all) and then examined the clone.

If the disk was mounted in Windows specifically, there might be Windows access logs showing activity (by default Windows logs lots of stuff - like booting up, logging in, and so on - that can be used to tell when the system was used) but those logs are usually stored on the system volume and in any case are possible to overwrite with some effort.

There *might* be ways to examine data outside of the file system to determine if the disk was used. The disk firmware might contain some kind of access records. The disk might have some non-volatile (flash memory) cache, which could potentially reveal what was accessed recently (more easily if you could read the cache directly but that would probably require modified firmware). There are perhaps other techniques that computer forensics experts know. However, checking most of these things is not going to be easy, requiring at least some special-purpose software and potentially requiring very expensive specialty hardware.

For practical purposes, you could probably determine the positive case with some confidence, but you can't prove the negative. If somebody else had physical access to your hard disk, and the data on it wasn't encrypted, it's much easier for them to have stealthily pulled it off than for you to prove whether or not they did.

Comment: The timeframe was around 4-5 hours. For purposes of convenience I assume a pendrive-based method of access to avoid leaving traces on the host system. Something either Linux or Windows/DOS-based. The data drives are consumer-level HDDs. I don't think any possible intruders in this scenario would have the expertise to do things like mess with the system volume--more likely just plugged in the drives, the PC, and booted the USB to copy something off. I was wondering if an operation like that would leave any traces on the data drives. Thanks.

Comment: If it had no boot drive at the time then there isn't a system volume to mess with, other than the one on the hypothetical removable drive. 4-5 hours is plenty to clone most drives, though.

Comment: Much obliged! Thanks for clearing some things up for me.